# External js file is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've dragged and dropped `.js` file in my `ASP.NET` project and still it is unresponsive while the code is working fine in inline js. I am using VS 2017.

here's my code;

```
<script src="externaljavascript.js"></script>
```

my input button is;

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="isEven()" value="button" />
```

and my JavaScript code is;

```
function isEven() {
  var num = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
  if (num % 2 == 0) {
    alert(num + " " + "is even");
  } else {
    alert(num + " " + "is odd");
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you import your js?

Comment: Please consider the way that you have import your JavaScript file and addressed that in your layout or other .cshtml file.  Do you have any error in your browser's console window? (use F12 key and check the console tab). If your file has not imported correctly, you will see the proportional error, like isEven is not a function  and etc.

Comment: If you had no error in console, check the isEven function working. I mean, in console panel, open the source tab (chrome), put a bullet beside the line: var num= document...... (by clicking beside the line) and then refresh the page (F5). the breakpoint will be activate, press F10 and then check the 'num' value (hover the mouse on variable). The value is not as expected, most probably, since  ('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>') has rendered serverside.

Comment: it worked,thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

As your javascript contains ('`<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>`') server side code which need to be render before going on client side so it cannot be separated in to JS file (i.e. externaljavascript.js).

('`<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>`') this piece of can render inside .aspx page

Comment: Sir,i have tried it, its not working either.Incase of me being wrong, kindly guide me through.Thankyou

        <script src="externaljavascript.js">
         var num = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID 
           %>').value;
            </script>

Comment: <%=TextBox1.ClientID %> 
you cannot write this in JS file.